# Instalação do Laravel 4 em servidor remoto

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Como instalo o laravel 4 num servidor remoto via composer?

Eu procurei intensamente na internet e não achei nenhuma resposta convincente que estivesse de acordo com boas práticas ou com a filosofia do framework.

Comment: Se conectar no servidor via SSH e instalar um projeto com L4 via linha de comando é uma possibilidade?

Comment: Downbeat pode ser mais específico em o que quer dizer para você instalar o laravel num servidor remoto? Você se refere ao processo de subir uma aplicação feita em sua maquina para o servidor?

Comment: As explicações e novos detalhes que você está fornecendo nos comentários da resposta do gmsantos deveriam ser adicionadas na pergunta, como explica a mensagem de suspensão acima. Depois de [edit] a pergunta, ela vai parar numa fila de análise para reabertura, onde se pode votar para tal.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha empresa utilizo um repositório git que a partir de um [hook post-receive](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) disparo um comando `composer install` no código que foi feito o deploy.

É algo bem simples, porém requer um certo conhecimento de git e de sistemas operacionais.

---

Se for seguir a filosofia do framework, leia a [documentação<sup><sup>en</sup></sup>](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2) do Laravel que você encontrará informações valiosas.

Para a gestão dos ambientes o Laravel conta com o [Homestead<sup><sup>en</sup></sup>](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead), que nada mais é que uma VM do Vagrant para você desenvolver a sua aplicação em uma configuração que o Laravel irá funcionar sem problemas.

Para a parte do deploy, o Laravel conta com o [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/), um ambiente que configura serviços de [PaaS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plataforma_como_servi%C3%A7o) que podem hospedar sua aplicação. Temos um curso gratuito no [Laracast<sup><sup>en</sup></sup>](https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge) que mostra de forma bem didática como utilizar esse serviço.

Agora, se você usa um servidor compartilhado ou você deseja gerenciar seu PaaS na mão, você terá que criar seu fluxo de trabalho para atender suas necessidades, que podem ser de algo simples a bem específico.

Leitura recomendada:

- [DevOps - Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps)
- [fortrabbit - hospedagem para aplicações PHP](http://fortrabbit.com/)
- [Ferramentas de Automação para PHP](http://br.phptherightway.com/#ferramentas_de_automao)

Comment: Apesar de você trazer alguns assuntos interessantes, você não respondeu a pergunta diretamente

Comment: @GustavoNunes a resposta simples e direta é: acessar o servidor remoto (Via ssh ou qualquer outro método) e executar `composer create-project laravel/laravel`. Porém acredito que não foi essa a dúvida do OP. Mais tarde posso revisar a pergunta mas não vejo isso como motivo de downvote.

Comment: O Problema é que se eu executar composer create-project laravel/laravel via ssh ele vai instalar a pasta pública e o restante dos diretórios do framework, o que não me parece muito adequado, não é? Eu gostaria de saber como deixar a pasta pública do laravel em meu document root e o restante num nível acima.

Comment: gmsantos gostaria de agradecer seu empenho na resposta. Valeu!

Comment: @downbeat  é servidor compartilhado?

Comment: Eu tenho uma revenda kinghost. Acredito que sim.

Comment: @Downbeat encontrei essa post na comunidade do laravel brasil no g+. Parace que o Kinghost não é tão flexível para hospedagem de app no laravel. Para ser mais claro na sua pergunta, acho importante [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/38122/edit) sua pergunta incluindo mais informações (Exemplo que você usa kinghost, deseja fazer o delpoy, etc..). Isso facilita que uma pessoa que possa responder não precise caçar comentários.

Comment: Vamos lá curto e grosso. Quero colocar a pasta public do laravel no meu document root e o resto num nível acima. como faço?